# Add a default mp3 extension to file name that already does not have mp3 extension

Tags: php

I have a website where users upload mp3 files and get a link. All the files are upload from a form to the database table. But the problem is that some of the files being uploaded  do not contain .mp3 extensions I think this is because of the devices users have they save audio files with just name.

here is an example url to the file  :

```
www.example.com/images/my_audio
```

As you can see **.mp3** extension is missing.

And I want this link to appear like this (with a default .mp3 extension)

```
  www.example.com/images/my_audio.mp3
```

How can I validate the image name during upload and add an extension if it is without extension?

I tried with str_replace()

```
 str_replace(" ",",".mp3",$file);
```

But it does not seem to work.

Any idea?

Comment: "How can I validate the image name during upload?" What do you mean by image name ? You mean to valid the file, if it's a mp3 file or not ?

Comment: Images?  That str_replace() is.... just not a str_replace().   Is the name of the file contained in $file?   Or is that just a guess like the str_replace() syntax ?

Comment: i want to make sure the uploaded file has an extension, if not ,then I would like to add 1.

Comment: What if the extension they have is wrong?   What if it is an audio file in another format - do you want to add .mp3 to that as well?

Comment: I am using addhandler directive in apache to tell the server to process them as mp3

Comment: Downvoters : Please add an explanatory comment!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
if(preg_match('/mp3/',$file))
{
  echo 'It has extension';
}
else
{
  $file .= '.mp3';
}
```

Comment: Nope, try with input:  $file = 'mymp3file';    It says it has an extension :P

Comment: Try this and see
preg_match('/ \.mp3/ ',$file)

Comment: Eventually `/\.mp3$/` would be the correct pattern, but that would only validate the file name and not the file. So I could rename `myDocFile.docx` to `myMusic.mp3` and then go wonder why the music player can't read it...

Comment: He doesn't seem to care whether the contents of the file is actually an mp3 though :P

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one-liner you could always use

```
preg_replace("/(.+)(?<!\.mp3)$/i", "$1.mp3", $file_name);
```

First argument to `preg_replace` says

1. Grab any text `(.+)`, as long as the
2. Text immediately before the end of the line (EOL = `$`) is *not* `.mp3`: `(?<!\.mp3)`

At this point there are two possibilities.  Depending on if the user had an .mp3 extension at the end of the file name, either we've found something that matches the two criteria above, or we haven't:

- If you do have something of the form of XYZ.mp3 it just gets returned as-is, which is the desired behaviour.  This is because it failed criteria #2 and did not get [grabbed](http://image-cdn.zap2it.com/images/MrBananaGrabber-Charity-Drive-2.gif).
- Otherwise, the second argument to `preg_replace` says we take the text we grabbed (`$1`), and append `.mp3`.

The word on the street is true though.  You really should verify that the file data is in fact an mp3.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at the pathinfo() function, which can give you the various pieces of the filename.